# Chrome session cookies too long for database column

Tags: google-chrome, flask, cookies, flask-session

I'm implementing server-side session cookies using [Flask-Session](https://github.com/fengsp/flask-session).

The implementation largely works fine, but I encounter the following error when using Chrome to access my API:

`sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (pymysql.err.DataError) (1406, "Data too long for column 'session_id' at row 1")`

Here's the schema of my sessions table (flask_sessions_table) (as generated by the flask extension):

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| session_id | varchar(255) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| data       | blob         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| expiry     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I don't experience this error on any other major browser (Firefox, Chromium, Safari, Postman, etc). It appears the session cookies sent from Chrome to my Flask-based app are too long (~300 characters, sometimes even ~1200), whereas from other browses they're about ~50 chars max. See this attached image:

[image: session cookie on chrome - too large!]

This error is causing my app (API server) to crash since flask-session fails to save the session cookie on every request coming in. I thought of the following workarounds but they couldn't work:

1. convert flask_sessions_table.session_id from varchar(255) to LONGTEXT. SQLAlchemy (ORM) doesn't seem to support Text types?
2. truncate and save the first 255 chars from the chrome cookie. There doesn't seem to be a way to 'intercept' the request before saving the session cookie: the extension saves the cookie right away before statements on my request routes are executed

**Any other ideas on how to fix this for Chrome?**

UPDATE:
I have observed that when the domain is is 'localhost', the cookies are longer than 255 chars, whereas when accessing the same exact instance from [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), they're normal (~43 chars). What is it about Chrome on localhost that might cause the long session cookies?

Comment: Can you change the server to send special cookies beginning with "begin" and ending with "end"?

Comment: Hi @curiousguy, when/where might I be able to do that from on a Flask server, on every request? Also, what would this change introduce/achieve?

Comment: I would directly alter the code that generate the cookie. At least the cookies would stop looking random looking.

Comment: I wish I could control how the cookies are generated, but actually can't, hence the problem I've described. I just receive the cookies from the client side and store them on the server-side. I'm only able to control the cookies coming from my frontend app, but not those coming from browsers

Comment: Browsers don't invent cookies. They are either sent by a server or set by JS code.

Comment: Fair enough. All I'm saying is that I don't know how Chrome 'generates' the long cookies it's sending to my server. As you can see from the screenshot, I'm accessing my localhost instance of the server *on Chrome* and somehow, I'm receiving a session cookie of 341 characters. I don't know where the JS might be coming from. What I know is that my server is not generating any cookies

Comment: The JS code can only be on that exact same domain. (Or a browser extension.)

Comment: Hmm, do you know what JS code might be on localhost, or which kind of browser extensions typically create/set session cookies?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue except with Firefox. I was able to resolve it by clearing cookies on my browser and restarting Flask.